# Properly groupby and filter with Polars

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I have df for my work with 3 main columns: `cid1, cid2, cid3`, and more 7 columns `cid4, cid5, etc`.

`cid1` and `cid2` is `int`, another columns is `float`.

Each combitations of `cid1` and `cid2` is a workset with some rows where is values of all other columns is different. I want to filter df and receive my df with only max values in column `cid3` for each combination of `cid1` and `cid2`. `cid4` and next columns must be leaved without changes.

This code helps me with one part of my task:

```
df = (df
    .groupby(["cid1", "cid2"])
    .agg([pl.max("cid3").alias("max_cid3")])
)
```

It's receives only 3 columns: `cid1`, `cid2`, `max_cid3` and filter all rows when `cid3` is not maximal.
But I can't find how to receive all another columns (`cid4, etc`) for that rows without changes.

```
df = (df
    .groupby(["cid1", "cid2"])
    .agg([pl.max("cid3").alias("max_cid3"), pl.col("cid4")])
)
```

I tried to add `pl.col("cid4")` to list of aggs but in column I see as values different lists of some `cid4` values.

How I can make it properly? Maybe Polars haves another way to make it then groupby?

In Pandas I can make it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df["max_cid3"] = df.groupby(['cid1', 'cid2'])['cid3'].transform(np.max)
```

And then filter df wherever `cid3==max_cid3`
But I can't find a way to make it in Polars.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In polars you can use [Window functions.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/window/)

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"cid1": [1, 2, 2, 1, 3],
     "cid2": [1, 2, 2, 1, 3],
     "cid3": [1, 2, 9, 1, 1],
     "cid4": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     "cid5": [4, 5, 4, 9, 3]}
)
```

```py
df.with_columns(max_cid3 = 
   pl.col("cid3").max().over("cid1", "cid2")
)
```

```py
shape: (5, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ cid1 ┆ cid2 ┆ cid3 ┆ cid4 ┆ cid5 ┆ max_cid3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64      │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 4    ┆ 4    ┆ 1        │
│ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 5    ┆ 5    ┆ 9        │
│ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 9    ┆ 6    ┆ 4    ┆ 9        │
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 7    ┆ 9    ┆ 1        │
│ 3    ┆ 3    ┆ 1    ┆ 8    ┆ 3    ┆ 1        │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────────┘
```

You can use it directly inside `.filter()`

```py
df.filter(cid3 = pl.col("cid3").max().over("cid1", "cid2"))
```

```py
shape: (4, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ cid1 ┆ cid2 ┆ cid3 ┆ cid4 ┆ cid5 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 4    ┆ 4    │
│ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ 9    ┆ 6    ┆ 4    │
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 7    ┆ 9    │
│ 3    ┆ 3    ┆ 1    ┆ 8    ┆ 3    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Pandas for comparison

```py
>>> df.to_pandas().groupby(["cid1", "cid2"])["cid3"].transform("max")
0    1
1    9
2    9
3    1
4    1
Name: cid3, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It's the best:

df.filter(
    pl.col("cid3") == pl.col("cid3").max().over(["cid1", "cid2"])
)
Thank you!

Comment: "window function" 404

Comment: @alancalvitti - Fixed, thanks.